# Unable to use MapBox basemap in CartoDB

Tags: carto, mapbox

I am trying to embed a MapBox basemap that was created in the new studio (just came out a couple weeks ago) and when entering the MapID/URL and the Access Token in the CartoDB interface I get an error that says the URL is invalid. I am copying the URL that MapBox provides for sharing styles.

Do I need to pay for MapBox to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Mapbox API seems to have been changed and CartoDB is adapted for the old URLs they used.

The issue was reported [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/6157) in the CartoDB repo.

EDIT: The issue has been updated, and the outcome is:

Mapbox doesn't provide a way to transform their vector tiles to image tiles, so we can't use their new maps into CartoDB as they render tiles by using WebGL.